# AutoScrolling a WebView Android

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I want to autoscroll my WebView, what's the best way to approach? I have tried the following but doesn't seem to be working.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wv.loadUrl("www.google.com");
    wv.scrollBy(0,2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Android (Java) based code failed to achieve the purpose, hence resorting to html/Javascript method (courtesy: http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/scroll.html).

Please add the following code to your html page between the HTML 'head' tags.

```
    <script>
    function pageScroll() {
        window.scrollBy(0,50); // horizontal and vertical scroll increments
        scrolldelay = setTimeout('pageScroll()',500); // scrolls every 500 milliseconds, controls scroll speed
    }
    </script>
```

And instead of a plain html 'body' tag  add the following to it

```
    <body onLoad="pageScroll()">
```

I have tested this code on desktop chrome and firefox browsers and it works fine, but on android devices the
character encoding fails thereby leading to erratic display of the html content.

Comment: Thanks for replying but that doesn't seem to be scrolling down the page.

Comment: I've tested this piece of code both on the emulator as well as the ACER android tablet device prior to posting here. I've used the URL "www.google.com". Please let me know what's the URL/html link that you are using in your code.

Comment: Please look at the file name "1.html" on the bottom which is the file that I want to be scrolled automatically when the webpage loads and stops when the html page has reached to its end. And I want the scrollBy speed of scrollBy(0,1).
https://sites.google.com/site/gurbaniujagar/page1

Comment: Modified the answer, pure Java code did not work for the html file that you had provided. Try the new method (its better since this can work on even non android devices like ios etc... ). Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be working on Chrome. Thanks for your effort but unfortunately it's not working on Android devices. Also, saving this in to HTML file will leave this for permanent. I was looking for something when the user enables the option to load scroll the page it scrolls until it has reached to an end. I tried using wv.setPictureListener(new PictureListener()) and then putting in the code w.scrollBy(0,1). That does work but it never stops and continues to work even after the HTML file has reached to an end. Anyways, +1 for your effort. Thank you! :)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Unfortunately the method setPictureListener() was deprecated in API level 12. Will keep you informed, if I stumble across a working solution. Thanks